Where and how to store a long text (article) in supabase
I'm not a back end expert and I've just taken up learning supabase. As a project, I'm trying to build an affiliate marketing website where users can share articles about stuff. So, I created a table named articles, with columns of author, text and title, and some others.
And my question is how I should store the text. Should I just copy and paste it in the text column of the article table? Or is there a better and specific way to store articles on database, like using a json file? If json file is an option, how should I form it? as it must be one line as far as I know.
I tried checking on the internet and also ChatGPT3.5 and wasn't able to sort it out. So, I need some help and guidance here.

Column type text is what you are looking for.
